# Is it possible to send Cordova exec command from external web to cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins

My question is that is it possible to send cordova.exec() from external web to cordova app ?

Below is the detail scenario of my requirement...

I built an Android app with cordova cle,
          ( CordovaActivity )

and implement pluginA,

I'm sure this plugin can successful run when I use cordova.exec inside the app.

In the other side, I use webView to load external page,

like this loadURL("some webpage I'd wrote.").

In that webpage, I include cordova.js and send cordova.exec( pluginA ); ,

but nothing happened instead of getting alert dialog.

( gap_init:2 )
( gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","messageChannel","CoreAndroid555630745"] )
( gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","show","CoreAndroid555630746"] )

> **In short:** Can we use cordova.exec() to invoke native plugin from an external web page?

Thanks All.

Comment: I don't understand what you want: Do you want to dynamically inject a plugin? If so, that doesn't work, because the plugins have a native part.

Comment: Not really,
the plugin is already implement in app.
I just want  to call cordova.exex() to run the plugin from external web page.
Any idea ?
Thanks for replying.

Comment: How do you open the webview to show third-party website?

Comment: Just use loadUrl command to load external page.

Comment: Which cordova version did you use?

Answer (score -1):

From what I had read, your issue seemed to be you want to load an external web url directly inside a Cordova app. From your external web source codes, you want to be able to perform native calls through cordova.

If that is what you want, you can use the [cordova-plugin-remote-injection](https://github.com/TruckMovers/cordova-plugin-remote-injection).

What it does is when you load an external url, it automatically injects the plugins you had installed within your Cordova application. Afterwards, you can use the variable `cordova` in your external source code.

The whole process is really simple, just install the plugin and the rest is automatically done for you.

Just remember to update your `index.html` file within your `Cordova` application. and set the `meta` to something like this allow the injection to take place.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="gap://ready file:;script-src 'self' data:;">`